# JSON to dataset in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I am facing an issue for which I am seeking your help. I have a task to convert a `JSON` file to `dataSet` so that it can be loaded into `HIVE`.

### Code 1

```java
    SparkSession spark1 = SparkSession
                  .builder()
                  .appName("File_Validation")
                  .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
                  .getOrCreate();
    Dataset<Row> df = spark1.read().json("input/sample.json");
    df.show();
```

Above code is throwing me a NullPointerException.
I tried another way

### Code 2

```java
    JavaRDD<String> jsonFile = context.textFile("input/sample.json");
        Dataset<Row> df2 = spark1.read().json(jsonFile);
    df2.show();
```

created an RDD and passed it to the spark1 (sparkSession)

this code 2 is making the json to a different format with header as

```
 +--------------------+
 |     _corrupt_record|
 +--------------------+

with schema as - |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)
```

Please help in fixing it.

Sample JSON

```json
  {
    "user": "gT35Hhhre9m",
    "dates": ["2016-01-29", "2016-01-28"],
    "status": "OK",
    "reason": "some reason",
    "content": [{
        "foo": 123,
        "bar": "val1"
    }, {
        "foo": 456,
        "bar": "val2"
    }, {
        "foo": 789,
        "bar": "val3"
    }, {
        "foo": 124,
        "bar": "val4"
    }, {
        "foo": 126,
        "bar": "val5"
    }]
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON should be in one line - one json in one line per one object.
In example:

```
{ "property1: 1 }
{ "property1: 2 }
```

It will be read as Dataset with 2 objects inside and one column

From [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets):

> Note that the file that is offered as a json file is not a typical
>   JSON file. Each line must contain a separate, self-contained valid
>   JSON object. As a consequence, a regular multi-line JSON file will
>   most often fail.

Of course read data with SparkSession, as it will inference schema

Comment: @skjagini Yes, now it has changed. Thanks, I forgot to update answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You cant read formated `JSON` in spark, Your `JSON` should be in a `single line` like this  :

```
{"user": "gT35Hhhre9m","dates": ["2016-01-29", "2016-01-28"],"status": "OK","reason": "some reason","content": [{"foo": 123,"bar": "val1"}, {"foo": 456,"bar": "val2"}, {"foo": 789,"bar": "val3"}, {"foo": 124,"bar": "val4"}, {"foo": 126,"bar": "val5"}]}
```

> Or it could be multi-lined JSON [like](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/10e1c0e638774f5d746771b6dd251de2480f94eb/examples/src/main/resources/people.json) this :

```
{"name":"Michael"}
{"name":"Andy", "age":30}
{"name":"Justin", "age":19}
```

Comment: So just like in my answer ;)